# SQL query help - Join on second table, possible?

Tags: sql

Two questions.

One: How would I be able to join two tables together, which are not the original FROM 'x' table?

Example: Grabbing all the reports and that users level name.

```
Report            
id | user_id      
1    1

User            
id | level_id      
1    1

Level            
id | level_name      
1    Admin

SELECT      report.id,
            report.user_id,
            level.name
FROM        report
INNER JOIN  user
ON          report.user_id=user.id
INNER JOIN  level
ON          user.level_id=level.id
```

Doesn't seem to work.

Two: How to join tables not from a 1-1 but a 1-many?

Say I wanted to:

```
SELECT * FROM user JOIN report ON user.id=report.user_id WHERE user.id='4'
```

But only join with the most recent report ordered by date desc?

I know it seems like I am asking you to do my work for me, but I just need to know what to use to accomplish this, not necessarily you coding it. Thanks.

**UPDATE:**

First question: Fixed, thanks
Second question:

I'll show you my query to make better sense, I didn't explain it well. I meant a many-many relationship where I grab a list of users and their latest report!

```
SELECT
    user.id
FROM 
    user
<< INNER JOINS ON OTHER TABLES >>
INNER JOIN
    (
        SELECT 
            report.id
        FROM
            report
        WHERE user.id=report.user_id
        ORDER BY
            date
        DESC
        LIMIT 1
      )
```

Comment: Why doesn't your query  work? It looks ok. Whats the error message?

Comment: What do your results look like from the query in your first question? That query looks right to me, it should be working. For your other question, if you have a 1-many relationship, and you only want one of the rows on the many side to show up, then you need to apply a filter. In your example, you probably need to join on a sub query instead of joining directly to the table.

Comment: Yeah I had an error with column names, when I rewrote in here (wasn't a direct copy and paste) I re-wrote column names for simplicity. First one works! Second one I am struggling with Nested selects

Comment: The subquery needs to go next to user.id

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your second question:

MySQL-style:

```
SELECT *
FROM user
INNER JOIN report re
  ON re.id = (SELECT id 
              FROM report 
              WHERE user_id=user.id 
              ORDER BY report.date DESC
              LIMIT 1)
WHERE user.id='4'
```

Comment: Cant do it this way, I need a nested one because I am selecting a list of users and their latest report.

Comment: Works for me, however, what if I need to report more columns from the report, rather than just id?

Answer (score 0):

One: Looks good to me, but shouldn't that be level.level_name in the SELECT clause?

Two: If you just want the most recent report it would be something like...

```
SELECT TOP 1 * FROM user JOIN report ON user.id=report.user_id WHERE user.id='4' order by report.date desc
```